# Access mail attachement with PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to access a mail attachement file in PHP?
If yes, is it a lot of work to do?

Someone want to send me .csv files in a mail address and want my php app to access the mail box, take the last mail, download the attachment file and upload it in the app.

It sounds weird to me. I'm not sure it's really possible or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy with using a third party system to help you then check out Mailgun. I have used them a lot in the past for the exact sort of situation you describe. Signup for a free account and then set up a route, e.g. all incoming emails get sent to a PHP script you upload to your server.

In your PHP code you will be POSTed the data of the incoming emails. All attachments are then accessible via `$_FILES`

Here is some code to illustrate what I mean:

```
$hash = hash_hmac('SHA256', $_POST['timestamp'] . $_POST['token'], 'your-key');

if($hash == $_POST['signature']) {

    if(count($_FILES)) {
        foreach($_FILES as $f) {
            /* do something with the file */            
        }
    }   


}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. And without a third party system, do you think that is too much work to do? I will be using symfony for my php app. @Chris